# Pushing a new element into an array after every iteration

Tags: python, numpy

I have to arrays that i need to separate.

```
A = np.array([1, 10, 23, 42, 15, 352, 3, 3, 9, 10, 51, 92, 30, 32, 41, 42, 45, 2, 3, 4])
```

and array B.
Then, i want to separate the first 5 elements from A into B

```
B = A[:5]
```

Now what i gotta do is loop through A starting from the 5th element and after every iteration ***add 1 element*** from A into B

```
for i in range(A[5:]):
    B = A
    print(B)
```

However this gives me:

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar
> index

Excepted output when i print B

```
[1, 10, 23, 42, 15]
[1, 10, 23, 42, 15, 352]
[1, 10, 23, 42, 15, 352, 3]
[1, 10, 23, 42, 15, 352, 3, 3]
[1, 10, 23, 42, 15, 352, 3, 3, 9] 
...
[1, 10, 23, 42, 15, 352, 3, 3, 9, 10, 51, 92, 30, 32, 41, 42, 45, 2, 3, 4]





      2 B = A[:5]
      3 
----> 4 for i in range(A[5:]):
      5     B = A
      6 

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: What's the `B=A` supposed to do?  Remember, this is Python!

Comment: This would work better with lists than with numpy arrays.

Comment: I need to call some functions for every iteration using the ith value in A that expects arrays

Comment: `range` expects **1** number, not an array.

Comment: I should have complained right away about the missing traceback.  It would have saved all of us time.

Comment: I added the traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `range` does not accept an array as an argument. You may want to iterate the remaining part of the array `A` directly. Then, the idea is indeed to use the `np.append` function, but to store it in `B` in each iteration in order to push the elements from `A` into `B`:

**Python script**

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1, 10, 23, 42, 15, 352, 3, 3, 9, 10, 51, 92, 30, 32, 41, 42, 45, 2, 3, 4])
B = A[:5]
for i in A[5:]:
    B = np.append(B, i)
    print(B)
```

**Output**

```
[  1  10  23  42  15 352]
[  1  10  23  42  15 352   3]
[  1  10  23  42  15 352   3   3]
[  1  10  23  42  15 352   3   3   9]
[  1  10  23  42  15 352   3   3   9  10]
[  1  10  23  42  15 352   3   3   9  10  51]
[  1  10  23  42  15 352   3   3   9  10  51  92]
[  1  10  23  42  15 352   3   3   9  10  51  92  30]
[  1  10  23  42  15 352   3   3   9  10  51  92  30  32]
[  1  10  23  42  15 352   3   3   9  10  51  92  30  32  41]
[  1  10  23  42  15 352   3   3   9  10  51  92  30  32  41  42]
[  1  10  23  42  15 352   3   3   9  10  51  92  30  32  41  42  45]
[  1  10  23  42  15 352   3   3   9  10  51  92  30  32  41  42  45   2]
[  1  10  23  42  15 352   3   3   9  10  51  92  30  32  41  42  45   2   3]
[  1  10  23  42  15 352   3   3   9  10  51  92  30  32  41  42  45   2   3   4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterator only accepts iterable objects like [list], so if you want to use A[5:] as a list, write like this:

```
for i in A[5:]:
    B = A
    print(B)
```

Is this output what you want?
If not, try this:

```
for i in A[5:]:
    print(i)
```

or

```
for i in A[5::5]:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
B = A[:5]

for i in A[6:]:
     #B.append(i)
     np.append(B,i)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Edited  above. Changed to np.append

Comment: What's `np.append` supposed to do?  It's a good idea to demonstrate that your answer works.

Comment: I don't think your answer does what you think it does

Comment: The array `B` does not expand since the output of the append function is not stored in `B`.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.